# Why arp spoofing only attack layer 2

Tags: man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing

I am studying network security.

I am wondering about ARP Spoofing. As you know ARP and ICMP only work at Layer 3 (network). But ARP spoofing attacks layer 2 (data link: mac address table).

I don't understand the problem.

Comment: You are completely wrong about ARP being layer 3. That's why you are confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/5067/2413) answer, ARP is layer 2 packet. Also from Wiki you can find this:

> The Address Resolution Protocol is a request and response protocol whose messages are **encapsulated** by a **link layer protocol**

You might be confused because of OSI model. However, ARP was not developed in the OSI networking framework.